# How to implement XProc in BaseX

Tags: pipeline, basex, xproc

I am working on a project where I must follow multiple steps at the time of data ingestion into the BaseX Database. I want to define these steps in XProc for the ease. Specially we need DOCX to DocBook and DocBook to DOC converstion.

My BaseX version is 8.6.44. I tried *https://github.com/fgeorges/calabash-basex-steps* but it is not supported. I tried to import some jar into BaseX but not working.

Please help me to start XProc on BaseX.

Comment: You state that it (BaseX?) is not supported. What happens if you follow the instructions in the referenced GitHub project?

Comment: I am receiving error "[bxerr:BXRE0009] Package version is not supported". I think calabash-basex-0.4.0.xar not supports BaseX version 8.6.44.